# Image and HTML5 video won't have the same height

Tags: css, html, cross-browser, html5-video, responsive

I am trying to make image and video align and be responsive.

Now my problem is the video won't align the same as the image as it won't take the whole parent size

```
display: list-item;
list-style-type: none;
```

Making it `list-item` fixed it on Chrome but won't fix on Firefox because it wants it to remove this to work.

```
 list-style-type: none;
```

Problem is it's having the dot thingy on its side.

```css
.wrap-thumbnails-div {
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 30px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.img-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.thumbnails-div {
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 16.6%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-thumbnails-div">
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/405x292?text=405x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href=""><video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="false" loop="">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/405x292?text=405x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/405x292?text=405x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/405x292?text=405x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href=""><video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="false" loop="">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/405x292?text=405x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/405x292?text=405x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/405x292?text=405x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/405x292?text=405x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href=""><video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="false" loop="">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/405x292?text=405x292"></a>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Also in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wargodz009/7ssgpudp).

Comment: Adding pictures of what you expect in different browsers would help clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:flex to align your images and thumbnails and set their respective flex-basis as 16.6 (100/6) to equally divide between them.
You need your images to have the `same aspect-ratio as your video` since you can't resize your video but you can `clip or resize your image` according to it. Here's the demonstration:

```css
.wrap-thumbnails-div {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px 0;
  width: 100%;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  display:flex;
}

.img-fluid {
  max-width:100%;
  flex:1 1 16.6%;
}

.thumbnails-div {
  flex:1 1 16.6%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-thumbnails-div">
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x292?text=510x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="">
      <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="false" loop="">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x292?text=510x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x292?text=510x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x292?text=510x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="">
      <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="false" loop="">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x292?text=510x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x292?text=510x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x292?text=510x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x292?text=510x292"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="">
      <video width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="false" loop="">
        <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnails-div">
    <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/510x292?text=510x292"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a smidge of javascript:

```
//assuming all images are same size, get the height of the first image
var imgheight = document.querySelector("div.thumbnails-div > a > img:first-of-type").parentNode.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect().height;

var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video");

//since width is set to 100% and height auto you will get videos with same width as images with space on top/bottom
for (var i=0; i<videos.length; i++){
    videos[i].height = imgheight;
}
```

working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7ssgpudp/3/